# Must have to duties order

Tags: modal-verbs

According to my book "English Grammar in Context" by Michael Vince "must" and "have to" can both be used but it does not say if in these examples either can also be used.

I read that in duties either "must" or "have to"  can be used for example,  "Everyone must/have recycle as much as possible."
But in other examples "You must keep this door locked", an order "You must be more careful" and "You must return the books on time" (said by a librarian)and "visitors must report to reception on arrival"  "must" is used because it's said by the person present. But "have to" can also be used if it's not said by the speaker present  but if  it's because of  someone else or it is a law/rule. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of grammar, *must* or *has/have to* can be used in any of those examples, whether said by someone present or not.

The word *must* has a more formal, official feeling, and would likely be used in a written notice.

The phrase *have to* sounds less official, and could be more of a description or recommendation.

(In your example
"Everyone must/have recycle as much as possible."
the word *have* is incorrect. The form would be *has to*.)

Comment: Is "have to" used only if the speaker is not present in this situation?  For example, (Doctor to patient) "It's really important to take this medicine three times a day " 

Should I use "must" or "have to"? "You must/have to take this medicine three times a day."

Comment: It's from "English Grammar in Context" by Michael Vince. It's also mentioned in "Practical English Usage" by Michael Swan that if the obligation comes from someone else then "have to" is used but in modern English "must" is still used in such situations. But in the quoted example "the speaker" as Michael Vince says  thinks it's important to take the medicine and  suggests using "must". Can both be used here as well?

Comment: The only correct answer it suggests is "You must take this medicine three times a day."

Comment: As I suggested in my answer, "have/has to" could be a description or recommendation rather than an order. "Must" has the connotation of an order. In the doctor/patient example, the doctor could use either phrase. In a conversation, "you have to" is more likely.

Comment: Thus the difference is in style not in meaning as "must" is formal and expresses an order in my original examples. Right?    Michael Vince in "English Grammar in Context"  explains in  his examples "You must be carefull" is a speaker's personal opinion" while "You have to be careful" an outside opinion or rule" but with the first person there is little difference sometimes  between "I have to go" and "I must go". But according to the book there is a difference between them  when "have to" and "must"  are used   with "you".

Comment: When you said "In terms of grammar, must or has/have to can be used in any of those examples, whether said by someone present or not" do you mean that there is no difference between them in meaning? Do you agree with the book's explanation that  "must" with "you"  means it is important  for the speaker but with "have to" it is an outside rule? "You must keep the door locked" or "You have to keep the door locked"

Comment: I am sorry, but it's not easy :(.

Comment: @AntoniaA I don't think the lines for "must/have to" are as sharp as that, at least not to me. If you want to see real examples of the uses, check google books.

Comment: Thank you! :)))